# Short story where a man owns creatures that build statues of him

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, religion

I am trying to recall the name of a story I read when I was fairly young (maybe 20 years ago, but not sure how old the story is).

What I remember: A man acquires a set of creatures that he keeps in his house, I think in an aquarium.  They evolve over time, quickly, and think of him as their benevolent god. They build statues in his likeness.

Then, I believe some sort of accident happens, and the statues they build become a little less benevolent, which bothers him.  This pattern continues on with his cruelty increasing and their depiction of him becoming more cruel.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's [Sandkings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandkings_%28novelette%29) by George R. R. Martin.

The critters see the owner as a god and build statues of his face in the sand.

Comment: Thank you!  I guess I shouldn't be surprised I like yet another R.R. Martin story.

Answer (score 21):

The story you are thinking of is called [Sandkings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandkings_%28novelette%29) by George R. R. Martin. It is his only Hugo and Nebula winning story. It was also turned into an episode of the Outer Limits in 1995 by Showtime.

Comment: Thanks Thaddeus.  I will have to see if I can track down that episode as well.

Comment: Yes I remember the outer limits episode now.  If I remember right it didn't seem to follow the written story very well. and was a little disappointing. This is not surprising as the books/stories have more details and are  more  unaltered

Comment: @FeyRay To be honest the original story doesn't have a lot of details. It's more of a "concept" story typical of scifi/horror.