# Short story about color-coded ant-people

Tags: story-identification

This is a short story that I read when I was a teenager in the 80s.  It is about this man who buys an ant farm that contains ant-sized human creatures of different colors.  He acts as their "god" providing food and they worship his image.  Later on he decides to ration the food in order to make them go to war against each other which they do.  Of course from there some unexpected things happen including the ant-sized creatures escaping the farm and so on.
Specifically, I remember that the orange anta had a special role in the development of the story.

thanks!

Comment: Sandkings by George R.R. Martin - duplicate of [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/94345/short-story-about-4-coloured-beetle-like-aliens-in-a-terrarium) and [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33183/identify-story-a-man-owns-creatures-that-build-statues-of-him).

Comment: @gowenfawr Could you post that as an answer so the OP can confirm it's the right one?